# Docker environment taking a long time to load data on LAMP app

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, codeigniter-3, lamp

Our site uses PHP and codeigniter 3 and mysql.

We have created an environment as follows:
Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
# installs mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
# enables mod_rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite 
# enables mod_headers
RUN a2enmod headers

RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache
```

Docker Compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - testVolume:/var/www/html/

volumes:
  testVolume:
```

We have tried every solution we could find online or from docker support and still our web pages take 10+ seconds to load. Any help would be appreciated.